# Laravel 5.3 multiple user databases attempt login

Tags: laravel, authentication, multi-tenant

I have two sets of users in two different databases. But how do I check both database.users tables? I was thinking something along the lines like this?

```
$user = new User;

$user->setTable('other-database.users');

// or

$user->setConnection('other-database');

if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
} else {
    dd('nope');
}
```

Comment: 2 tables for different types of users?, might want to look at your database design again.

Comment: Two databases with a users table in each. Does that make sense?

Comment: @dave_the_dev it makes sense alright, but it's not a good design. You can achieve what you desire in the question by setting the default connection on the queries.

Comment: @Sandeesh are you able to provide an example please?

Comment: @dave_the_dev added examples in the answer

Comment: Are you going to have more than 2 databases? (like multitenancy?) If no, you need to redesign your database. If yes you need to take completely another approach and study up **multitenancy** it is hard hard topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple models from different connections then you can specify the connection to use on your model by adding the `$connection` property.

```
protected $connection = 'connection-name';
```

With query builder you can set the connection to use on the fly.

```
$users = DB::connection('connection-name')->select(...);
```

You can do this similarly with eloquent.

```
$user = User::on(‘connection-name’)->find(1);
```

Comment: thanks for the above. I tried this before but i need a way to change it dynamically. I'll have to look into multitenancy